# Visual C++.Net database programming

Tags: database, visual-c++

Where do you recommend someone to start if he wants to do database programming using visual C++.Net?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235423%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

is probably a good place to start.